# Upper index does not seem to work with iexact Django field lookup

Tags: django, database, postgresql, indexing

I have some references (strings) that I want to use to filter a query with a case-insensitive exact match. To do so, I used `iexact` Django field lookup.

```
Model.objects.filter(column1__iexact=reference)
```

Since I have a very large number of rows on that table, I wanted to create an index to speed up the query. Django uses the UPPER function to perform the `iexact` lookup.
So I created the following migration (DB is Postgresql):

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('app', 'previous_migr'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunSQL(
            sql=r'CREATE INDEX "index_name_idx" ON "table" (UPPER("column1") );',
            reverse_sql=r'DROP INDEX "index_name_idx";'
        ),
    ]
```

Unfotunately, this index does not seem to be used while querying.

Why do I think this ? Here are the request times with :

- iexact ~= 17s
- exact < 1s

Here is the generated (truncated) SQL query :

```
SELECT "table"."id" FROM "table" 

WHERE (
    "table"."is_removed" = false 
    AND (UPPER("table"."column1"::text) = UPPER('blablabla') 
    OR UPPER("ordering_order"."column2"::text) = UPPER('blablabla'))) 
ORDER BY "table"."id" ASC
)
```

Is there something wrong with my migration ? Any other option to do this query with good performance ?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter with the `Upper` expression in the query, so:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Upper

Model.objects.annotate(
    column1_upper=Upper('column1')
).filter(column1_upper=reference.upper())
```

or in [django-3.2](/questions/tagged/django-3.2), we can work with a [**`.alias(…)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#alias) to boost performance slightly more:

```
Model.objects.alias(
    column1_upper=Upper('column1')
).filter(column1_upper=reference.upper())
```

The above is however *not* a case-insensitive search. It is a common mistake to assume that two items are equivalent when you convert both to lowercase/uppercase. For example in German, the [*eszett ß*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F) has as uppercase `'SS'`, other characters do not have a lowercase/uppercase variant. In order to match case invariant, you need to take a look at casefolding.

Comment: Upper should be imported from `django.db.models.functions`
>>> `from django.db.models.functions import Upper`

Comment: @shwz: yes, that was indeed a typo. Thanks!